# How to overcome effect of intensity variation in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-smoothing

I want to process an image for which I need the method to be robust to lighting conditions. For that the only thing I can think of is normalising intensity. I did this by dividing the image with average intensity and then scaled the values to be between 0-255. This method doesn't seem to work well. What other approach can I follow to make my processing robust to variation in lighting conditions?

Comment: Does the average intensity varies across the image?

Comment: Yeah it varies as there my algo works when there are atleast 2 light sources but fails when there are 1 light sources kf same intensity...so the mean changes

Comment: the median and alpha trimmed mean are more robust than the mean

Comment: I should add, more robust in a statistical sense, but maybe not in your approach

Comment: It eventually depends on what kind of processing you intend to do, and whether the contrast changes locally or not. Contrast-invariant algorithms come in various flavors. Also, mathematical morphology (opening, erosion, top hat...) is a field whose purpose is the design of contrast-invariant algorithms.

Comment: @sansuiso, I think you should expand a bit and post it as an answer.